# Is there any simple software to make your Comic stripes?

Tags: open-source, drawing, animation

I can make a good hand drawing comic strips, but unfortunately I have no idea how to digitize them. Actually, I want to know the process of converting hand drawn comic strips to digital one. But, this is not the platform to ask such questions.

So, it will be kind of you, if you suggest a software (apart from Photoshop) to create comic strips. I do it as hobby, I don't want to create comic for any particular professional or academic purposes.

Just I like to share my insipid humor on-line.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend Inkscape or gimp for free ( illustrator & photoshop alternative). I use Afinity photo & designer each cost around 50$  if you can afford you will love them. Don't forget to send some comics as treat :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you can draw well, you can scan your comic stripes, then with a photo editor extremely enhance the contrast so to have it in pure black and white (open source software for this can be gimp, cross platform, or paint.net.

When you have your polished picture you can use a tracing tool that converts a bitmap image to a vector drawing (I use potrace from the command line)

The end result is a smoother and resizable strip.

**Links:** (edited)

- To see how Potrace works (online tool): http://kilobtye.github.io/potrace/# (you can upload your image or use a test image provided)
- Potrace source: https://sourceforge.net/projects/potrace/

Answer (score 2):

[Krita](https://krita.org/en/) is an Open Source suite for artists, directly competing with proprietary tools used in the industry such as Clip Studio Paint.

Unlike *Gimp*, which is an image manipulator, Krita is made for creating and refining art. It also has support for [Vector layers](https://docs.krita.org/en/user_manual/vector_graphics.html#), making line art more efficient. *Combine this with [Andrea's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/60835/50659) for generating vector graphics out of your lineart and you'll have a good time.*

They also have [templates for comics](https://docs.krita.org/en/user_manual/templates.html) according to their documentation, however you can make your own templates and open them as necessary.